# Error 133000 when using multiple contexts with core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I've spent days trying every possible solution I can think of to this problem, but nothing seems to be working.

I run a background thread like this:

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

                    Media *localMedia = [media inContext:localContext];

                    UIImage *image = localMedia.thumbnail;


                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        [thumbnails setObject:image forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
                        [contentDict setObject:thumbnails forKey:@"MediaItems"];
                        [cell.entryView setNeedsDisplay];
                    });

                }];
```

Or like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t cellSetupQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.Journalized.SetupTimelineThumbnails", NULL);
            dispatch_async(cellSetupQueue, ^{

                NSManagedObjectContext *newMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
                NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread].persistentStoreCoordinator;
                [newMoc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

                NSNotificationCenter *notify = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
                [notify addObserver:self
                           selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                             object:newMoc];

Media *localMedia = [media inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread];

                        UIImage *image = localMedia.thumbnail;


                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                            [thumbnails setObject:image forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
                            [contentDict setObject:thumbnails forKey:@"MediaItems"];
                            [cell.entryView setNeedsDisplay];
                        });

                    }];
```

Both of these give me a crash with UIImage returning as nil object, and a `Cocoa Error 133000`.

I've removed every other piece of background threading code, and have saved on the main thread directly before this just to make sure. Running the code above on the main thread also works, but freezes up my UI. Despite all of these efforts, the above code crashes every time.

I'm not sure what to do to make this work.

Edit:

My question, specifically, is how do I make this work without crashing? It seems to be a problem with objects from 1 context not existing in another, but how do i make them exist in another context?

Comment: What is your question? You are using RestKit? And your code snippets are very incomplete - I can't follow anything. The observer method is almost definitely not what you want and the first example probably crashes due to something inside saveInBackgroundWithBlock:

Comment: This may be happening because Core Data isn't thread safe. Have you tried [localContext performBlock:^{}];

Comment: @PauldeLange I'm not using RestKit, no. What should I have as an observer method instead?

Answer (score 2):

Remember, the MR_inContext: method is using [NSManagedObjectContext objectWithID: ] method under the covers. You should look in there to make sure your object has:

1) Been saved prior to entering into the background context/block in your first code block
2) This method is returning something useful

I'm also not sure how you set up your thumbnail attribute. Ideally it shouldn't matter as long as you have the NSTransformable code write (there are samples on the internets that show you how to save a UIImage in core data using the transformable attribute)

Also, your code should look like this:

```
UIImage *image = nil;
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

  Media *localMedia = [media inContext:localContext]; //remember, this looks up an existing object. If your context is a child of a parent context that has contains this, the localContext should refresh the object from the parent.

  //image processing/etc

  image = localMedia.thumbnail;

} completion:^{              

    [thumbnails setObject:image forKey:@(i)]; //new literals are teh awesome
    contentInfo[@"MediaItems"] = thumbnails;  //as is the new indexer syntax (on the latest compiler)

    [cell.entryView setNeedsDisplay];

}];
```

Comment: "Been saved prior to entering into the background context/block in your first code block" was my problem. In my background thread I was fetching items that hadn't been saved in the main thread yet.

Answer (score 1):

Fast answer:

> NSManagedObjectReferentialIntegrityError         = 133000,
>    // attempt to fire a fault pointing to an object that does not exist (we can see the store, we can't see the object)

EDIT:
It's pretty difficult to see something from the code. What is a managed object there?

I suppose the problem is that you are using temporary objects from one context in another context.

Comment: To be fair there was never a question, but this is not an answer either.

Comment: @PauldeLange I got the impression that he didn't even know what the error code means so adding error description was the first thing before even looking at the code.

Comment: And how do i make the objects non-temporary?

Comment: You have to save them. Using multiple contexts is not easy. Have you considered using only one shared context?

Comment: @Sulthan Contexts aren't thread safe. I need to work on a background thread for some things.

Comment: @Andrew You can lock the context when necessary.